# How to implement autocomplete in multiple select dropdown with Materialize CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, materialize

I want to implement autocomplete feature in Multiple Select type of Dropdown with Materialize CSS (materializecss.com)

There are multiple values which I have to select. Currently, as the list is very long we have to scroll down. I want to implement an autocomplete search functionality that selects multiple dropdown values based on the current Materialize CSS Framework used.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.